# I don't understand how /* i */ is unreachable?

Tags: c#

```
int counter = 0;
string lastTwo = str.Substring(str.Length-2, 2);
string currentTwoChar = null;

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) //why is i unreachable?
{
     currentTwoChar = str.Substring(i, 2);

     if (currentTwoChar == lastTwo)
     {
          counter++;
     }
     return counter;
 }
```

I must be missing something obvious, and it's late at night, but why is i++ unreachable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) //why is i unreachable?
{
    currentTwoChar = str.Substring(i, 2);

    if (currentTwoChar == lastTwo)
    {
        counter++;
    }

}
return counter; // Put it here instead
```

Comment: right in front of me and I couldn't see it!  Thanks!

Comment: It happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

See the place where you have used the return statement. it will definitely get executed during the first iteration regardless of any conditions, so there will not be any chance for executing `i++` or the second looping. The compiler identified this situation and warn you. So you have to change the place of return statement or re think about the logic that you are suppose to implement.

Above answer solves your issue if it is fine to return the value after all iteration, you can try this as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) //why is i unreachable?
{
   // conditional return
    if(some_other_condition)
    {
       return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I was staring at the screen for so long without seeing the obvious

Comment: @Jay Cool happy to help you